# initialization using ClassName.Type in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In UIKit, if we use UITableView programmatically, we need to register UITableViewCell or our CustomCell. 
Like ...

```
tableViewInstance.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "blah blah");
// OR if we want to use our Custom Cell
tableViewInstance.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier : "blah blah");
```

The point is, how does Apple Guys' UITableView know what type of cell we gave to register and how does it initialize the cell by our given type internally.

Comment: `CustomCell.self` *is* the type. What is the actual problem?

Comment: The actual problem is  how do they initialize `CustomCell()` using `CustomCell.self`. @MartinR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIKit is – as far as I know – still written in Objective-C, but
even in Swift you can create an instance from  class type,
as in the following simplified example:

```
class MyTableView {

    var registrations: [String: UITableViewCell.Type] = [:]

    func register(theClass: UITableViewCell.Type, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String) {
        registrations[identifier] = theClass
    }

    func dequeueCell(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let theClass = registrations[identifier] else {
            fatalError("No class has been registered for \(identifier)")
        }
        return theClass.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }
}
```

Here `theClass` has the type `UITableViewCell.Type`, and you
can create an instance by calling the

```
init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
```

method on it. For initialization from a "metatype value", the
`init` method must be referenced explicitly, so

```
return theClass(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
```

would not compile.